# Adjust node level using phantom node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, node-connections

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners = 2pt, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  block/.style = {treenode, rectangle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black},
  phantom/.style = {}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 3in/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}] 
  \node [block] {P1}
    child {node [block] {P2}
      child {node [block] {P3}
        child {node [block] {P4}}
        child {node [block] {P5}}
      }
    }
    child {node [block] {P6}
      child {node [phantom] {}
        child {node [block] {P7}}
      }
    }
    child {node [block] {P8}
      child {node [block] {P9}
        child {node [block] {P10}}
      }
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am using the phantom node to get P7 at the same level as P4, P5 and P10.

But in place of the phantom node, I get some blank space, the connector from P6 terminates theres and a new connector starts from that blank space to P7.

How do I get a straight connector from P6 to P7? Generally, how do we adjust 'level' of various nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case in which the power of the [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) can be helpful; the `tier` key let's you get the desired alignment with no effort (notice also the shorter code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{
treenode/.style={
  align=center, 
  inner sep=2pt, 
  rounded corners=2pt,
  minimum width = 2cm,
  font=\sffamily
  },
block/.style={
  treenode, 
  rectangle, 
  white, 
  font=\sffamily\bfseries, 
  draw=black, 
  fill=black
  },
  phantom/.style = {}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
for tree={
  block,
  edge={->,>=latex},
  where level={0}{s sep=1.5cm}{}
}
[P1
  [P2
    [P3
      [P4]
      [P5,tier=last]
    ]
  ]
  [P6,before computing xy={s=(s("!p")+s("!n"))}
    [P7,tier=last]
  ]
  [P8
    [P9]
    [P10,tier=last]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code can be even shorter since the current labelling schema for the nodes can also be left to the package.

Comment: wish, I could upvote twice :) Very elegant!

Comment: I did not quite understand the `xy={s=(s("!p")+s("!n")` magic. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

This is a possible solution. To remove the space use `coordinate` instead of `node`, Here
`edge from parent/.style={draw=none}` is used to not draw the line from P6 to P7, then draw the (P6)--(P7) line manually.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
%\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners = 2pt, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, font=\sffamily},
  block/.style = {treenode, rectangle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black},
  phantom/.style = {},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',
level/.style={sibling distance = 3in/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}
] 
  \node [block] {P1}
    child {node [block] {P2}
      child {node [block] {P3}
        child {node [block] {P4}}
        child {node [block] {P5}}
      }
    }
    child {node [block](a) {P6}
      child {coordinate [phantom,edge from parent/.style={draw=none}] {}
        child {node [block](b) {P7}}
      }
    }
    child {node [block] {P8}
      child {node [block] {P9}
        child {node [block] {P10}}
      }
    }
  ;
\draw[->] (a)--(b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```